# Is there a way to view the stack memory in java?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, visualvm, jvisualvm

In Java I can use Visual VM to see the state of the heap with a heap dump. Is there any way to view the state of the stack memory?

I don't need this for any assignment but I am curious to view the memory structure of the stack.

Comment: You can trigger a core dump which you can inspect with a debugger. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes it might be. I will go and read about that. Thanks

Comment: The heap dump contains stack frames and their contained reference variables.